# First digit of a large number

Tags: no-computers

Can you find the first digit of

$2^{2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}}$?

Basically, it is $2$ to the $2$ to the $65536$ power.

You **cannot** use a computer, but are allowed to use a calculator.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh yes,it should be six twos.Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: By first digit, do you mean right-most or left-most digit?

Comment: Do you know that this is actually doable?

Comment: The question is "Can you find it?".  The answer is "Nope.".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I presume we are looking for the leftmost digit.

I don't think this is doable with a calculator.

For comparison and by way of warm-up, an easier, solvable problem is to find the first digit of $A = 2^{65536}$.

Simply use logarithms base 10.

$\log A = 65536 \times \log 2 = 65536 \times 0.301029995664... = 19728.3017958...$

Taking the antilog (exponentiation to the power 10), we get:

$A = 2.00352977045... \times 10^{19278}$

So the first digit is $2$. It's only the decimal places of $\log A$ which tell us this: the whole number part $19728$ only affects the magnitude. I.e. we needed to compute $\log A$ to at least $6$ significant figures. Easily done with a calculator.

However, if we turn to $B = 2^A = 2^{2^{65526}}$ and try a similar game, we get:

$\log B = (2.00352977... \times 10^{19728}) \times \log 2 = 0.603122557976... \times 10^{19728}$

So in order to find the first digit of $B$, we need to know the term $0.603122557976...$ to at least $19729$ significant figures. This is beyond the scope of even the most prodigious calculators.

EDIT: Adding info provided in a useful comment by Daniel Mathias (thank you, thank you):
OEIS has $20001$ digits for $\log 2$ (luckily this is greater than the required $19729$!), so computing (by computer) the exact value of $A=2^{65536}$ allows us to find $\log B$ with sufficient precision. The fractional part is $≈0.32634379468$ so $B≈2.12003872881×10^{10^{19728}}$

Comment: More accurately, $A\approx 2.003529930406846465 \times 10^{19728}$ and $\log B \approx 0.603122606263029537 \times 10^{19728}$

Comment: These considerations are exactly why I have a comment on the question asking whether the OP knows the thing is doable. Maybe there's some ingenious trick that makes it possible even though the "obvious" route is impassable, but I rather doubt it.

Comment: Yes @GarethMcCaughan it was your earlier comment that set me off on this path of thinking.

Comment: OEIS has 20001 digits for $\log 2$, so computing the exact value of $A = 2^{65536}$ allows us to find $\log B$ with sufficient precision. The fractional part is $\approx 0.32634379468$ and $B\approx 2.12003872881\times 10^{\text{I stayed up way too late for this}}$

Comment: How do you access OEIS without a computer?

Comment: @msh210 With a cellphone.

Answer (score -2):

If we can choose

> to answer in something other than base 10, then we can give our answer in base 2, in which case **the first (leftmost) digit is 1**. (and the rightmost digit is 0.)

The full solution

> in base 2 is $10000...000_2$, which is a 1 followed by $2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}$ $0$s, or a 1 followed by $2^{65536}$ $0$s
>
>
>  $2 = 2_{10} = 10_2 $, or a 1 followed by 1 zero.
>
>  $2^2 = 4_{10} = 100_2$, or a 1 followed by 2 zeros.
>
>  $2^{2^2} = 16_{10} = 10000_2$, or a 1 followed by $2^2$ zeros.
>
>  $2^{2^{2^2}} = 65536_{10} = 10000000000000000_2$, or a 1 followed by $2^{2^2}$ zeros.
>
>  $2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}$ is too large to write, but following the pattern we know it's a 1 followed by $2^{2^{2^2}}$ zeros.
>
>  $2^{2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}}$ is far too large to write, but following the pattern we know that it's a 1 followed by $2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}$ zeros.

I believe this answer is incomplete, however, because

> base 10 was used for the problem so is implicitly expected for the solution.
>
>
>  We could convert the full base 2 answer to base 10, but I'm not sure of a way to do that for such a large number which can be done on a calculator. Perhaps there's a clever way that solves it digit by digit.